# How to authenticate with SSH or HTTPS using exec

Tags: javascript, git, typescript

I'm working on a project using javascript to create an application able to execute git commands like clone, pull, push.

I'm using a library called simple git (https://github.com/steveukx/git-js) which allow me to do this using exec.

Exemple for git clone command :

```
const USER = 'something';
const PASS = 'somewhere';
const REPO = 'github.com/username/private-repo';

const git = require('simple-git/promise');
const remote = `https://${USER}:${PASS}@${REPO}`;

git().silent(true)
  .clone(remote)
  .then(() => console.log('finished'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('failed: ', err));
```

To execute for example the pull command, it works perfectly with HTTPS just by adding the username and password in URL :

```
const remote = `https://${username}:${password}@${REPO}`;
```

But now, i don't know how to authenticate with SSH.

Is there a way to authenticate using HTTPS or SSH with exec (child library, process.spawn).

We could also use credentials from git but the problem is that i need to put the password after the pull command for exemple but i can't using exec.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Automating an SSH session with keyboard interactive authentication is non trivial ans while there are some workarounds, I doubt it would work in TS. You should use key based authentication for Git SSH access. Generate an SSH key pair if you haven't already and add it in GitHub web interface.

Comment: I agree with marekful.  Use an SSH public / private key.  Saving passwords for ssh is always discouraged.

Comment: I already have a SSH key on my Git but i want to use Http or SSH. The problem is that i want to enter my username and my password with my exec command